# How can I shorten this XSLT snippet?

Tags: xslt, optimization

I have to repeat the following XSLT snippet like 100 times and I would like it to be as small as possible. Is there a way to make an equivalent XSLT snippet that is shorter?

```
<xslo:variable name="myVariable" select="//This/that/anotherthing" />
    <xslo:choose>
      <xslo:when test="string($myVariable) != 'NaN'">
        <xslo:text>1</xslo:text>
      </xslo:when>
      <xslo:otherwise>
        <xslo:text>0</xslo:text>
      </xslo:otherwise>
    </xslo:choose>
```

I'm basically setting the state of a checkbox based on whether or not a value exists in //This/that/anotherthing in the source xml.

Can be XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0, doesn't matter.

Comment: "*I have to repeat the following XSLT snippet like 100 times*" Why would that be necessary? In XSLT 2.0 you can create a function once and call it as many times as necessary. In XSLT 1.0, you can do the same thing using a named template.

Comment: So many good solutions. I don't know which one to choose. Hehe. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `if` instead of `xsl:choose` (XSLT 2.0 only)...

```
<xsl:value-of select="if (string(number(//This/that/anotherthing)) = 'NaN') then 0 else 1"/>
```

I also dropped the `xsl:variable`, but if you need it for some other reason, you can put it back.

You could also create a [function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-function)...

```
<xsl:function name="local:isNumber">
    <xsl:param name="context"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="if (string(number($context)) = 'NaN') then 0 else 1"/>
</xsl:function>
```

usage...

```
<xsl:value-of select="local:isNumber(//This/that/anotherthing)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<xslo:variable name="myVariable" select="//This/that/anotherthing" />
<xslo:value-of select="number(boolean($myVariable))"/>
```

Comment: `number(boolean('abc'))` returns 1. I don't think OP wants that.

Comment: $myVariable is a node-set not a string

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the purpose correctly - that is return 1 if the value in question can be successfully expressed as a number, 0 otherwise - then I believe:

```
<xsl:value-of select="number(//This/that/anotherthing castable as xs:double)"/>
```

would be the most straightforward way (in XSLT 2.0) to achieve it.

---

### Edit

***In view of your change of purpose:***

> I'm basically setting the state of a checkbox based on whether or not
>   a value exists in //This/that/anotherthing

That's even simpler:

```
<xsl:value-of select="number(boolean(string(//This/that/anotherthing)))"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, editing because it can be of any data type. Basically if it contains any value then it is set.

Comment: Nice! I like this one even better but I already accepted the other answer. Both are very good answers. Thanks!